# Searching on multiple phrases with or using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I have the following phrases for example:

`phrases = ['foo bar', 'baz qux']`
Using rails searchkick, how can I get matches that have any of those phrases in any of the fields?

I have tried this

`Model.search('foo bar baz qux', operator: 'or')`
and this
 `Model.search(['foo bar', 'baz qux'], operator: 'or')`

and this returned matches of any word, not the phrases.